# Can I change the output format for SHOW CONFIG when using mgconsole?

Tags: memgraphdb

In `mgconsole` (version 1.3) when I run SHOW CONFIG; query the output is hard to read.

`Memgraph Lab is running at localhost:3000

mgconsole 1.3
Connected to 'memgraph://127.0.0.1:7687'
Type :help for shell usage
Quit the shell by typing Ctrl-D(eof) or :quit
memgraph> SHOW CONFIG;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| name                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   | default_value
| current_value
| description
|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| "flag_file"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            | ""
| "/etc/memgraph/memgr`

[image: SHOW CONFIG;]

Can the output format be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a flag in Memgraph called `-fit_to_screen`. You need to use it before staring `mgconsole`. You can add this parameter to your `docker run` command.

```
docker run -e MGCONSOLE="-fit_to_screen" -it -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 -p 3000:3000 memgraph/memgraph-platform
```

It will result in output that will fit to your window size. Like this

[image: SHOW CONFIG output]